# Algorithm for extracting background from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

Good day. I have this set of geotagged photos. I want to build a system which approximate the location of a query image based on how similar it is from the geotagged photos. I will be using python and opencv to accomplish this task. However, the problem is that most of the geotagged photos have people on it (I'm only after the background scenery).

I found some face detection algorithms that I can use to detect people on photos. However, what I need is to detect the whole body of the people in the images and just leave out the background.

Opencv have algorithms which can be used in removing background (I was hoping to reverse the output and leave the background instead). However, this is only applicable to videos (subtracting static with moving parts).  Can you guys recommend any solution to this problem (where to start/ related studies/ algorithms)? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Look for inpainting, to fill the "hole" generated by removing the person

Comment: for whole body person detection you can use openCVs HoG person detector.

Comment: Having some sample data and some lines of codes of what you have done so far may lead to more detailed answers.

Comment: Seam carving also may help to remove objects from image http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/andrew/scs/cs/15-463/f07/proj2/www/lisachan/ see chapter 7. "Object Removal".

Comment: OPENCV has  few implementations of background subtraction but seem to require a video, i haven't looked deeply into it at this point I happened to come across this question as I only have a few images with a small occlusion and don't need to run across a full video http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html